# c++ Cartesian class not asking for user input

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

My program is supposed to ask the user to input two sets of coordinates at runtime. However, when I compile and run it it does not ask for any input and instead gives me this output

```
Please enter the first coordinates in the form x y: 
Please enter the second coordinates in the form x y:
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
```

How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

class Cartesian
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
public:
    Cartesian(double = 0, double = 0);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Cartesian&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Cartesian&);
};

Cartesian::Cartesian(double a, double b)
{
    x = a;
    y = b;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, Cartesian& num)
{
    in >> num.x; in >> num.y;

    return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream & out, const Cartesian& num)
{
    cout << "(" << num.x << ", " << num.y << ")" << endl;

    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Cartesian coord1, coord2;
    cout << "Please enter the first coordinates in the form x y: ";
    cin >> coord1;
    cout << "Please enter the second coordinates in the form x y: ";
    cin >> coord2;
    cout << coord1;
    cout << coord2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, if you include `<iostream>`, then you don't need `<ostream>` or `<istream>`. Those headers simply provide the I/O interface but not the instantiations `std::cout` or `std::cin`.

Comment: Also, [I'm not getting the same output as you.](http://ideone.com/I8ngFh)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you need to specially configure your project in order to recieve input from console

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/visualstudio/